# Jquery funciona no console, mas não funciona no arquivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou realizando um teste em um plugin no worpdress com formulário que possui select , onde que quando o usuário selecionar a opção com o "value:9" emita um alert ("Funcionando") e caso ele não selecione o esta opção emita um alert("Não está funcionando"), mas esse código que eu fiz só funciona no console do navegador, quando coloco ele no arquivo não funciona

Tentei com vários parâmetros do jquery, mas não obtive sucesso.

CÓDIGO JQUERY

```
$('.bookly-js-select-service').change(function(){
if($(this).val() == '9'){ 
alert("Funcionando");
} else {
  alert("Não funcionando");
}
});
```

CÓDIGO HTML

```
<select class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-service">
       <option value="">Escolher serviço</option>
       <option value="9">Avaliação Clínica</option>
       <option value="10">Avaliação de retorno ao trabalho</option> 
        <option value="11">Exame Toxicológico</option>
</select>
```

*****Mudei meu código jQuery *****
Mas mesmo assim não obtive sucesso, aparece até no console, mas a condição do if, não.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var eleLists = jQuery('.bookly-js-select-service:visible');
  console.log(eleLists.length);
  if(eleLists.length > 0){
    jQuery(eleLists[0]).change(function($){
    if(jQuery(this).val() == '9'){
    alert("Funcionando");
    } else {
      alert("Não funcionando");
    }
    });

  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Componente ainda não foi carregado!!");
  }



});
```

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Comment: Cara edita sua pergunta e coloca tb o código do seu select .bookly-js-select-service, já verificou se não é cache do navegador? O WP costuma sempre ficar no cache

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e posta o código html do WP onde consta o select. (executa um search e procura se existe mais de um ".bookly-js-select-service"). Não tem como saber só pelo seu script o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Aqui tá funcionando normal, no console e direto na página do browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isto e veja se funciona.

Utilizei o

> Document.Ready

com um $ no parameter (veja o post [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327085/jquery-ready-function-doesnt-work-in-wordpress))

pra certificar de que o elemento vai existir quando atribuir a função ao evento change **(pois creio que este é o mais provável problema)**. E também o

> :visible

pra pegar apenas o componente visivel na tela.

Existe também um pluggin na sua página que carrega os componentes, por isto o Document.Ready não será o suficiente. Até ter uma solução do próprio pluggin, você pode usar o SetInterval. Veja o exemplo.

**Lembre de limpar o cache do navegador**

```js
var intervalId = 0;

function addEventChange(){
    var eleLists = $('.bookly-js-select-service:visible');
      console.log(eleLists.length);
      if(eleLists.length > 0){  
      console.log("Agora Deu Bom!!!");
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        $(eleLists[0]).change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '9'){ 
        alert("Funcionando");
        } else {
          alert("Não funcionando");
        }
        });

      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Componente ainda não foi carregado!!");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function($){
  
intervalId = setInterval(addEventChange, 1000);
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-service">
       <option value="">Escolher serviço</option>
       <option value="9">Avaliação Clínica</option>
       <option value="10">Avaliação de retorno ao trabalho</option> 
        <option value="11">Exame Toxicológico</option>
</select>

<div style="display:none;">
<select class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-service">
       <option value="">Escolher serviço</option>
       <option value="9">Avaliação Clínica</option>
       <option value="10">Avaliação de retorno ao trabalho</option> 
        <option value="11">Exame Toxicológico</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Este é o seu código no WP. Veja que o script está antes do componente ser construido e sem o "document.ready".

[image: Script antes do componente]
[image: Select Oculto]

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95694/discussion-on-answer-by-elizeu-jquery-funciona-no-console-mas-nao-funciona-no-a)

Answer (score 0):

Verifique a ordem de leitura dos arquivos, o Wordpress tem muito desses problemas, aonde você está editando pode estar sendo carregado antes mesmo de qualquer jQuery, esses scripts é bom colocar para que sejam lidos depois.

Você pode fazer algo como:

```
function carregarScript(){
    wp_register_script( 
        'meuScript', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/meuScript.js', 
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'meuScript' );
}
```

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carregarScript');
A dependência do jQuery precisa ser uma array(), não apenas uma string. Isso forçará seu script a carregar após o jQuery.

'jquery' é necessário Na wp_register_script função. Ele diz ao WordPress que o jQuery é necessário para que este script seja executado, então ele será carregado de acordo. Em wp_enqueue_script que não é necessário, porque WP já conhece as dependências de antes.